# How to export cell values and add colunns to txt by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel files as follows.

[image]

I'd like to add columns `person`(as follows) to them and export them to `.txt` files.

I searched some information, but I couldn't figure out how to add columns.

[image]

Are there some sample scripts..?

If someone has opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: My opinion is [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). You haven't found how to add a column in an Excel sheet? I cannot believe that, the internet is full of examples and you can use the macro recorder to see how that code would look like.

Answer (score 1):

Just hover over column headers where you would like to insert column, right click it and there should be option "Insert column". So you have column for a `person`.

Now, having that filled, you can go to menu and "Save as...", then choose CSV format - it will save your file as CSV, which is basically text file. If you really want "txt" extension you can open that file in text editor and again "save as..." text file :) Or you even can do that by renaming file :)

To complete this answer:

> You can even save as text file from Excel directly.

Comment: You can even save as text file from Excel directly ^^

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Great suggestion! Never done that and did not expect it :D